# installing ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm learning ruby and I'm trying to install gems but i had some trouble installing gems:

```
$ sudo gem install rake
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem … in any repository
```

I don't know what to do.

I've tried to follow  instructions in this article:

> http://jacob.stanley.io/2010/10/27/sudo-gem-install-behind-a-proxy/

But unfortunately I saved changes to `/etc/sudoers.tmp` (although the article that i mentioned tells to do the opposite).

Please can you help me?

my operating system is mac os x 10.7.4, my ruby version is 1.8.7 and the result of $ which ruby is: /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: What operating system are you using? Ubuntu? OS X?

Comment: Did you use rvm to install ruby. Show results of `$ which ruby` and `$ ruby -v`.

Comment: my operating system is mac os x 10.7.4, my ruby version is 1.8.7 and the result of $ which ruby is: /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: You may consider to use rvm instead of this.

Comment: He's trying to install a ruby gem, not ruby itself.

Comment: The tutorial that you list gives some commands you can run to check that it's working. Can you ruin those commands and put the results into your answer above? eg `sudo env | grep http_proxy`

Comment: try command `sudo ruby -v` see if you can find ruby that way. Possible is that you have ruby only for user and not super user.